# Reactjs save state after refresh

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a simply authentication, but have some problem with what to show. In componentDidMount i  get information about сurrent user, then passing it to the Header, where in the if statement determine  state "page". With "changePage" i change this state after login or logout.
But my if statement in Header does not work correctly: after login it shows logout, but after refreshing the page it shows login despite the fact that this.props.currentUser exist

Edit:
Added some console.log with "this.props.currentUser" and when i am logged in :
[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9m6E.png)
Header:23 in ComponentDidMount so there are some problem with passing my currentUser from Main

Main.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {        
    currentUser: null,
  }      
  this.updateCurrentUser = this.updateCurrentUser.bind(this);      

}
componentDidMount(){            

  let that = this
  axios.get('http://localhost:3000/isUser',{
  })
  .then(function(response){
    console.log(response.data.email)

    if(response.data.email){
      that.setState({
        currentUser: response.data.email
      })
    } else {
      that.setState({
        currentUser: null
      })
    }
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
  })
}
updateCurrentUser(email) {
  this.setState({
    currentUser: email
  })
}   



 render(){ 
       
    return <Header updateCurrentUser={this.updateCurrentUser} token = {this.props.ids.token} currentUser = {this.state.currentUser}/>

   
   
}
```

}

Header.js

```
class Header extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    if (this.props.currentUser == null){
      this.state = {
        page:"login"
      }
    } else{
      this.state = {
        page: "delete"
      }
    }
  
    this.changePage = this.changePage.bind(this);
  }
 
changePage(newPage) {
    this.setState({
      page: newPage
    })
  }
render() {
    switch(this.state.page) {
      case "signup":
         
        return <Signup changePage={this.changePage} updateCurrentUser={this.props.updateCurrentUser} token = {this.props.token} currentUser = {this.props.currentUser}/>
      case "login":
        return <Login changePage={this.changePage} updateCurrentUser={this.props.updateCurrentUser}token = {this.props.token} currentUser = {this.props.currentUser}/>
      case "delete":
        return <Logout changePage={this.changePage} updateCurrentUser={this.props.updateCurrentUser} token = {this.props.token} currentUser = {this.props.currentUser} />
    }}}
```

Comment: Hi @Melon8991 will it be possible to show the entire code of both Main and Header components? or at least try to extract the code to the bare minimum that shows what the pronlem is

Comment: You cannot set state directly:

  this.state = {
    page:"login"
  }
should be replaced everywhere like this with setState function:

this.setState({
        page:"login"
      });

Comment: @charly1212 Its not work, i am even trying to use my if statement in componentDidMount  with setState. And my this.state in controllet, so it should be fine,isn't it?

Comment: @RicardoSanchez Added entire code

Comment: The **state** on your **Header** component is not setup properly

Comment: @RicardoSanchez What exactly? I added some console log and it looks like my currentUser in Header is default null anyway before return

Answer (score 0):

Try setup the state in your **Header** component like so:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        page: (this.props.currentUser) ? "delete" : "login"
    }
  
    this.changePage = this.changePage.bind(this);
}
```

**UPDATE**
You may also try this:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        page: ""
    }
  
    this.changePage = this.changePage.bind(this);
}
```

then

```
onComponentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.currentUser == null){
      this.setState = {
        page:"login"
      }
    } else{
      this.setState = {
        page: "delete"
      }
    }
   
}
```

Same as you implemented the state on your Main component. The state on the Header component is not setup properly, you have to update only using the `setState` method

Comment: Its not work. I think problem with passing currentUser from main, In return main i can see   currentUser and in return Header, but in componentDidMount Header its null like default in Main

Answer (score 0):

Some problem with passing currentUser to my Header and just transfered page and changePage to Main. Now it works

```
class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(){
          super();
          this.state = {
            page:"",
            currentUser: null,
          }
      
      this.updateCurrentUser = this.updateCurrentUser.bind(this);
      this.changePage = this.changePage.bind(this);


    }
    componentDidMount(){
              

      let that = this
      axios.get('http://localhost:3000/isUser',{
      })
      .then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data.email)

        if(response.data.email){
          that.setState({
            currentUser: response.data.email,
            page:"delete"
          })
        } else {
          that.setState({
            currentUser: null,
            page:"login"
          })
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
      })
    }
    updateCurrentUser(email) {
      this.setState({
        currentUser: email
      })
    }
    changePage(newPage) {
      this.setState({
        page: newPage
      })
    }
    

  render(){  console.log(this.state.currentUser)
           
        return <Header updateCurrentUser={this.updateCurrentUser} token = {this.props.ids.token} currentUser = {this.state.currentUser} page = {this.state.page} changePage={this.changePage}/>
    
       
       
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you solved your problem with your own answer the yes by all means